# Java Convert Object[] Array to Vector

Tags: java, arrays, java-me, vector

What's the best way to convert an Object array to a Vector?

JDE < 1.5

```
public Vector getListElements()
{
  Vector myVector = this.elements;
  return myVector;
}
```

this.elements is an Object[]

Thanks,
rAyt

**I should clarify my question**

My target platform is a blackberry.

Collections aren't supported. Array.asList() isn't, either :/

Full Class

```
package CustomElements;

import net.rim.device.api.ui.component .*;
import net.rim.device.api.collection.util.*; 
import net.rim.device.api.util.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ContactsList extends SortedReadableList implements KeywordProvider
{
    // Constructor
    public ContactsList(Vector contacts)
    {
        super(new ContactsListComparatorByFirstName());    
        loadFrom(contacts.elements());      
    }
    // Add Element to ContactsSortedReadableList
    void addElement(Object element)
    {
        doAdd(element); 
    }   

    public Vector getListElements()
    {
        return new Vector(Collection


        Vector test = this.getElements();
    }
    // getKeywords
    public String[] getKeywords(Object element) 
    {
        return StringUtilities.stringToWords(((Contact)element).get_contactFirstName());
        // return StringUtilities.stringToWords(element.toString());
    }  
    //  Comparator sorting Contact objects by name
    final static class ContactsListComparatorByFirstName implements Comparator
    {                           
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2)
        {
            // Sticky Entries Implementation
            if(((ContactsListObject)o2).getSticky())
            {
                return 1;
            } else
                if (((ContactsListObject)o1).getSticky())
                {
                    return -1;
                } else
                {
                    if(((ContactsListObject)o1).get_contactFirstName().compareTo(((ContactsListObject)o2).get_contactFirstName()) <0)
                    {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    if(((ContactsListObject)o1).get_contactFirstName().compareTo(((ContactsListObject)o2).get_contactFirstName()) >0)
                    {
                        return 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
        }        
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
return new Vector(Arrays.asList(elements));
```

Now, it may look as if you are copying the data twice, but you aren't. You do get one small temporary object (a `List` from `asList`), but this provides a view of the array. Instead of copying it, read and write operations go through to the original array.

It is possible to extends `Vector` and poke its `protected` fields. This would give a relatively simple way of having the `Vector` become a view of the array, as `Arrays.asList` does. Alternatively, just copying data into the fields. For Java ME, this is about as good as it gets without writing the obvious loop. Untested code:

```
return new Vector(0) {{
    this.elementData = (Object[])elements.clone();
    this.elementCount = this.elementData.length;
}};
```

Of course, you are probably better off with a `List` than a `Vector`. 1.4 has completed its End of Service Life period. Even 1.5 has completed most of its EOSL period.

Comment: Wow, second solution looks, just so elegant!

Comment: I think "inventive" needs quotes. :)

Answer (score 2):

In J2ME, you're stuck iterating over the array and add the elements one by one.

```
Vector v = new Vector();
for (int i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
    v.add(this.elements[i]);
}
```

Comment: Should I understand why Research in Motion provide something like SortedReadableList which has an LoadFrom Method, but no LoadTO Method?! :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the array elements to the `Vector`, or
2. Use `Arrays.asList(...)` to return a `List`, which isn't exactly a `Vector`, but you should be coding the `List` interface anyway.

Comment: So, no way around a for loop?

Comment: I suggest option 2 except it is worth noting that this does not take a copy of the array, it only wraps it. I wouldn't suggest option 1 i.e. don't use a vector unless you really need to.

Comment: @rAyt: Even if there was a built-in function to do so, it would still use a for-loop behind the scenes. There is no magic :)

Answer (score 1):

imho your only viable option is:

```
public Vector getListElements()
    Vector vector = new Vector(this.elements.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
        vector.add(this.elements[i]);
    } 

    return vector;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, seems that way. going to suck copying 1000+ objects in the objects array.

Comment: If you're concerned about it, you could toss in an initialCapacity of elements.length to the Vector constructor.

Answer (score 1):

A simplified comparator which does basically the same thing.

```
final static class ContactsListComparatorByFirstName implements Comparator {
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            // Sticky Entries Implementation
        ContactsListObject clo2 = (ContactsListObject) o2;
        ContactsListObject clo1 = (ContactsListObject) o1;
        if (clo2.getSticky()) return 1;
        if (clo1.getSticky()) return -1;
        return clo1.get_contactFirstName().compareTo(clo2.get_contactFirstName());
    }
}
```

Using generics and ?: it would be just

```
static final class ContactsListComparatorByFirstName implements Comparator<ContactsListObject> {
    public int compare(ContactsListObject clo1, ContactsListObject clo2) {
        return clo2.getSticky() ? 1 : // Sticky Entries Implementation
            clo1.getSticky() ? -1 :
            clo1.get_contactFirstName().compareTo(clo2.get_contactFirstName());
    }
}
```

But to answer your question... (oh I see Tom has what I would put already)

Comment: Generics aren't supported in my java version, either! But thanks for the hint +1

Answer (score 1):

A reasonably concise way to do it is something like:

```
Object[] xx = { 1, "cat", new Point(100,200) };
Vector vv = new Vector(Arrays.asList(xx));
System.out.println("vv=="+vv.toString());
```

But y'all knew that already, I guess.