# How to initialize a vector with an array in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, vector

Do I have to push my elements one by one? I tried something like

```
String[] array;
array=...
Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>(array);
```

but my eclipse marks this as an error.

Comment: FYI, use of `Vector` is mostly discouraged nowadays.  You should probably prefer `ArrayList`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116636/java-convert-object-array-to-vector

Comment: Define 'doesn't work'.

Comment: Er, here 'doesn't work' means my eclipse marks my code as an error.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`Vector` doesn't have a constructor that accepts an array directly.

Assuming that `array` is of type `String[]`, you could do

```
Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Better to use `ArrayList` as it doesn't have the overhead of having synchronized methods. You could use

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

This will produce a mutable collection also.

Comment: Provided that `array` is a `String`.

Comment: Or better yet `List<String> list = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(array));`, or even better yet `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(array));`

Answer (score 4):

That can't work, since, as [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html) shows, there is no Vector constructor taking an array as argument.

If you just want a non-modifiable list, use

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
```

If you really want a Vector (but you should use ArrayList instead, because Vector is obsolete), use

```
Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by 'one by one'. If you want to add an existing collection to a Vector, you could use [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#Vector%28java.util.Collection%29).

If you want to do it one by one, you need to iterate through the items, and call Vector's '[add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#add%28E%29)' method.

```
for(String item: array) {
    vector.add(item);
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid doing it one by one, thanks anyway:)