# Copy Object[] Array to Vector

Tags: java, arrays

I have a quick question. I have an array of objects (ODData) and I am trying to cope them into a multidimensional vector so I could do some clustering using Weka. I know it is really simple but for some reason I can't find a proper way in dong so.

```
new Clustering (routes);
............
............

public class Clustering {

  Vector <Vector<ODData>> myData = new Vector <Vector<ODData>>();

  public Clustering( ODData [] routes )
  {
    //What should I do here?        
  }
}
```

ODData consists out of three elements if it makes any difference.

Comment: Are you sure you need `Vector<Vector<ODData>>`? Because `ODData[] routes` can be converted into `Vector<ODData>`.

Comment: If it will keep all the elements of each object then it will work too @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: You have an array of ODData (`[a, b, c]` for example). You want a vector of vectors of ODData. How many vectors should the outer vector have? What would be the result of this transformation on `[a, b, c]`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Convert Object\[\] Array to Vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1116636/java-convert-object-array-to-vector)

Comment: Side note: Use `ArrayList` instead of `Vector` if you can. There usually isn't much reason to use the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void Clustering( ODData[] routes )
{
    Vector<ODData> routesVector = new Vector<ODData>();
    for (ODDatas s : routes) {
        routesVector.add(s);
    }
    myData.add(routesVector);     
}
```

Comment: `Vector<ODData> routesVector = new Vector<>(Arrays.asList(routes))` is less verbose.